# как инициализировать динамический массив CachedBitmap?

Tags: c++, gdi+

У меня в файле заголовка есть

```
std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap>**CachedBitmap;
```

в .cpp я пытался инициализировать так:

```
Bitmap* bit = new Bitmap(L"file");
Graphics graphics(hdc);
(CachedBitmap[0]) = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(bit, hdc);
graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap[0].get(), position.x, position.y);

std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(Bitmap* originalBitmap, HDC hdc)
{

    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    return std::make_shared<CachedBitmap>(originalBitmap, &graphics);
}
```

когда я запускаю программу, у меня возникает **ошибка исключения**:
CachedBitmap[0] **is nullptr**

после пытался так:

```
(**CachedBitmap) = std::make_shared<::CachedBitmap>((new ::CachedBitmap(bit, &graphics))[5]);
(*CachedBitmap[0]) = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(bit, hdc);
graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap[0]->get(), position.x, position.y);
```

ошибка **Gdiplus::CachedBitmap::CachedBitmap: невозможно получить доступ к private члену, объявленному в классе "Gdiplus"::CachedBitmap"**

Comment: `::std::vector<::std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap>> CachedBitmaps{};` а потом emplace_back

Comment: @user7860670 а через new как?

Comment: `::std::unique_ptr<::std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> []>> CachedBitmap{new ::std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> [5]};`